# iOS beta releases, separate from current stable development?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I remember reading something once, but could not find it now while searching, if there are things I need to worry about when installing an iOS beta.

If I install the iOS 6 beta, do I need to worry about it overwriting my current Xcode 4.2 (iOS 5.1) development?  Or does it install it in a separate location automatically?  Or is that all I need to do, in that I need to put it in a separate location when installing instead of the default location?

If I put a device on iOS 6 beta, it cannot be downgraded back to 5.1 right?

Are those the only things I need to worry about?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Apple states in the Xcode 4.5 Developer Preview Release Notes[1]: Xcode 4.5 comes as a single app bundle that can simply be dragged to the Applications folder. You can start it from there and it will not install or overwrite any existing developer tools like previous Xcode versions.

Apple states that

> Devices updated to iOS 6 beta can not be restored to earlier versions of iOS. Registered development devices will be able to upgrade to future beta releases and the final iOS 6 software.

But you may be able to downgrade your iOS device as long as version 5.1 is the official version served by apple by putting your device in the DFU mode. When Apple pushes iOS 6 for everyone you may be able to downgrade your device with TinyUmbrella[2]. This worked with previous versions but there is no guarantee it will work this time.

[1] http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_4.5_developer_preview/xcode_45dp_rn.pdf (an iOS Developer account may be needed to view this file)

[2] http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

I know that an iOS device running beta cannot be downgraded per the iOS Dev Center:

> Devices updated to iOS 6 beta can not be restored to earlier versions of iOS. Registered development devices will be able to upgrade to future beta releases and the final iOS 6 software.

And yes, I believe you can install multiple versions of Xcode at a time, including betas. The installer should ask you where to put it.

There's nothing else you need to worry about, but if you put the beta iOS software on your device, make sure you use a device dedicated to development or back up everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is creeping on NDA territory, but in general:

- Beta versions of Xcode cannot be used to submit apps to the App Store.
- Sometimes you can install two copies of dev tools on the same machine. In the past it hasn't always worked properly; now that all of Xcode is contained in the app bundle, maybe it will work more smoothly.

The safest thing to do is get an external hard disk, install Mac OS X on it, and then boot from it and install the beta tools on it. Then you can safely play around without messing up the release version.